# How to declare an enum constant to be a whitespace char?

Tags: java, enums, constants

I am writing a simple TicTacToe java program and I want to declare constants X, O and EMPTY(representing an empty space) using enum types. When I compile this program:

```
enum Constants
{
    X, O, EMPTY(' ');
}
```

I get an error pointing to the `EMPTY` constant saying:

`"constructor Constants in enum Constants cannot be applied to given types"`.

Any suggestions of how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think that's how enums work. Enums aren't strings. If you want to print X, O, or ' ' just make 3 enums, check which one you have, and print the corresponding string.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
public enum Constants {
  X("x"), 
  O("o"), 
  EMPTY("");

  public final String input;

  Constants(String input) { this.input = input; }

  public String getInput() { return this.input; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However the getInput method should be declared with a return type of a String instead of an int.